# How to find out average pixel value of an image, scanning it from top and bottom?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

So, I have an image and I want to scan the image from top upto 5 rows. After that, I want to calculate the average pixel color value of the scanned area. How to do it?

Same for scanning from bottom upto 5 rows.
[image: Image to scan]

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by "scan the image from top up to 5 rows"? Do you mean take the top 5 rows of pixels?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [np.average](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.average.html):

```
img = cv2.imread('img.jpg')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) #convert it to RGB channel
plt.imshow(img)
```

[image]

Let's crop the first 1000 rows(The first 5 rows in your image are white so the average will only be 255).

```
crop_img = img[:1000, :]
plt.imshow(crop_img)
```

[image]

If you want to average the complete cropped image (which includes 3 channels RGB) use:

```
np.average(crop_img)
> 221.7606454078586
```

If you want to average over 3 channels use:

```
np.average(crop_img, axis = (0,1))
array([219.85728484, 220.16578896, 225.25886241])
```

If you just want to average over a single channel, say red:

```
np.average(crop_img[:, :, 0]) #replace 0 with 1 for green channel and with 2 for blue channel
219.85728484414187
```

Similarly, you can use [np.mean](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html#numpy.mean)

Comment: this is honestly such a well-written answer – thanks so much!